# How to benchmark a SQL Server query using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to benchmark a SQL query within SQL Server. What is the best approach to accomplish this in the most accurate way?

My idea was as follows -->

- record start-time
- execute query
- record end-time
- perform a date diff between start-time and the end-time and output to milliseconds or microseconds.

Comment: It matters a lot if you have a warm or cold cache. To clear out your cache execute `dbcc dropcleanbuffers` before you run your query

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are looking for:-

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
```

Check [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190287.aspx) out.

> When SET STATISTICS TIME is ON, the time statistics for a statement
>   are displayed. When OFF, the time statistics are not displayed. The
>   setting of SET STATISTICS TIME is set at execute or run time and not
>   at parse time. Microsoft SQL Server is unable to provide accurate
>   statistics in fiber mode, which is activated when you enable the
>   lightweight pooling configuration option. The cpu column in the
>   sysprocesses table is only updated when a query executes with SET
>   STATISTICS TIME ON. When SET STATISTICS TIME is OFF, 0 is returned. ON
>   and OFF settings also affect the CPU column in the Process Info View
>   for Current Activity in SQL Server Management Studio.